# @Autowiredでのインジェクションに失敗する。

Tags: java, spring-boot

Spring BootでJUnitを使った簡単なテストを試したいと思っていますが、下記ソースを実行すると、`@Autowired`でのインジェクションに失敗し`NullPointerException`が発生します。
`@Autowired`を使用せずに

```
TestLogic testLogic = new TestLogic();
Hero testHero = testLogic.testMesod();
assertEquals(testHero.getHP(), "12");
```

とすれば正常に動きますが`@Autowired`を使用した形で処理がうまくいくようにもしたいです。
どう修正すればよろしいでしょうか。

```
public class SampleTest {

@Autowired
TestLogic testLogic;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JUnitCore.main(SampleTest.class.getName());
}

@Test
public void testOne() {

    Hero testHero = testLogic.testMesod();

    assertEquals(testHero.getHP(), "12");
}

public class Hero {

private String HP;
private String MP;
private String atackPower;

public String getHP() {
    return HP;
}
public void setHP(String hP) {
    HP = hP;
}
public String getMP() {
    return MP;
}
public void setMP(String mP) {
    MP = mP;
}
public String getAtackPower() {
    return atackPower;
}
public void setAtackPower(String atackPower) {
    this.atackPower = atackPower;
}

@Service
public class TestLogic {

    public Hero testMesod(){

     Hero hero = new Hero();
     hero.setHP("12");
    return hero;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

テストクラスに

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

を追加してみてください。

参考サイト：
[Testing Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html)
[Maven import](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test/1.2.3.RELEASE)